# Dynamodb: How to query the latest 10 items added to the table GLOBALLY

Tags: sorting, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have a table of "posts" where the primary key is partitioned on "id", which is unique for every post. Now I want to grab the 10 most recent posts pushed to the database.

I have a timestamp column, but using a GSI with a "dummy partition" to sort timestamp on every object would become slow as the number of rows grows.

Is there any way to just grab the the 'X' most recent items that were added to the database?

Comment: Which programming language do you wanna use?

Answer (score 1):

Having a GSI with a dummy partition key would not become slow, as you'll always only read 10 items.

##### My GSI

| PK | SK |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-11-01T20:00:000 |
| 1 | 2023-11-01T21:00:000 |
| 1 | 2023-11-01T22:00:000 |
| ... | ... |
| 1 | 2023-11-11T15:00:000 |

`SELECT * FROM mytable.mygsi WHERE PK = 1 LIMIT 10 DESC`

```
aws dynamodb query \
--table-name my-table \
--index-name my-gsi \
--key-condition-expression 'PK = :pk` \
--expression-attribute-values '{":PK":{"N":"1"}}' \
--no-scan-index-forward \
--limit 10
```

Comment: interesting thank you, is it because creating a GSI maintains separate instance of all the data, as sorted?

Comment: Yes if you choose to project all the items to the index. You can also choose to only project a subset to make your index smaller.